# UnPack / rePack android img with Ubuntu simg2img/make_ext4fs

Tags: android, python, linux, ubuntu, rom

I'm playing with these 2 tools on ubuntu 14.04.1 :

- simg2img
- make_ext4fs

The first tool work great. 
But when I try to compile the image changed with the second tool I have in output this error:

```
can't set android permissions - built without android support
```

I have installed these two tools with the official package of ubuntu and also with the package of debian that seems more updated.

Anyone can help me ?
How I can compile these two tools ?

Thank you,

**UPDATE**

I have write this script for compile this tool, but the error persist:

```
sudo apt-get install git zlib1g-dev gcc make libpcre3-dev

URL="https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core"
git clone --depth 1 "$URL" "$(basename $URL)"
URL="https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras"
git clone --depth 1 "$URL" "$(basename $URL)"
URL="https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libselinux"
git clone --depth 1 "$URL" "$(basename $URL)"


git clone "extras" "extras-build"

DIR=$(pwd)

cd "extras-build/ext4_utils"


gcc  -Wall \
    -o make_ext4fs \
    -DHAVE_ANDROID_OS -DHOST \
    -I$DIR/core/libsparse/include \
    -I$DIR/libselinux/include \
    make_ext4fs_main.c \
    make_ext4fs.c \
    ext4fixup.c \
    ext4_utils.c \
    allocate.c \
    contents.c \
    extent.c \
    indirect.c \
    uuid.c \
    sha1.c \
    wipe.c \
    crc16.c \
    ext4_sb.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/backed_block.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/output_file.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/sparse.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/sparse_crc32.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/sparse_err.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/sparse_read.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/callbacks.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/check_context.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/freecon.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/init.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/label.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/label_android_property.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/label_file.c\
    -lz \
    -lpcre
```

**UPDATE 2:**
This is the final code:

```
sudo apt-get install git zlib1g-dev gcc make libpcre3-dev

URL="https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core"
git clone --depth 1 "$URL" "$(basename $URL)"
URL="https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras"
git clone --depth 1 "$URL" "$(basename $URL)"
URL="https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libselinux"
git clone --depth 1 "$URL" "$(basename $URL)"


git clone "extras" "extras-build"


cd "extras-build/ext4_utils"


gcc  -Wall \
    -o make_ext4fs \
    -I$DIR/core/include -DANDROID \
    -DHAVE_ANDROID_OS -DHOST \
    -I$DIR/core/libsparse/include \
    -I$DIR/libselinux/include \
    make_ext4fs_main.c \
    make_ext4fs.c \
    ext4fixup.c \
    ext4_utils.c \
    allocate.c \
    contents.c \
    extent.c \
    indirect.c \
    uuid.c \
    sha1.c \
    wipe.c \
    crc16.c \
    ext4_sb.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/backed_block.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/output_file.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/sparse.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/sparse_crc32.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/sparse_err.c \
    $DIR/core/libsparse/sparse_read.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/callbacks.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/check_context.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/freecon.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/init.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/label.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/label_android_property.c \
    $DIR/libselinux/src/label_file.c\
    -lz \
    -lpcre
```

Comment: have you tried to run pkg-config on the latter package? pretty much  like android support should be switched on there.

Comment: Yes.. but this is seems an error because the package deb is so old...

Comment: Hi to all, with the code in the second update all works fine.
:D

Comment: Wasn't there a configure script and a makefile to do the work with? It's not that "official" this way :D

Comment: This script is not working on my Ubuntu 18. Please update it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for hours building make_ext4fs and then finally found a precompiled binary which I could run on my Debian system: http://blog.djodjo.org/?p=98

Repacking my system.img went flawless with this.